# how to create a between matrix calculations class in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a class that will be able to make all possible calculations between matrix. the input is a matrix (doesn't matter the size), and on that matrix the class should do any calculations - either multiply, combine or substract. The different functions are as follow:
I need to have in this class:

```
__init__(self, data)

get_width(self)

get_height(self)

add(self, m)

scalar_multiply(self, a)

subtract(self, m)

multiply(self, m)

compare(self, m)
```

Thanks alot, it also needs to be with simple actions.
This is my code till now:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_width(self):
        return len(self.data[0])

    def get_height(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def add(self, m):
        lines = []
        for j in range(len(self.data)):
            line = []
            for i in range(len(self.data[j])):
                line.append(self.data[j][i] + m[j][i])
            lines.append(line)
        return lines

    def scalar_multiply(self, a):
        res = []
        for j in range(len(self.data)):
            line = []
            for i in range(len(self.data)):
                line.append(self.data[j][i]*a)
            res.append(line)
        return res

    def subtract(self, m):
        lines = []
        for j in range(len(self.data)):
            line = []
            for i in range(len(self.data)):
                line.append(self.data[j][i] - m[j][i])
            lines.append(line)
        return lines

    def multiply(self, m):
        lines = []
        for j in range(len(self.data-1)):
            line = []
            for i in range(len(m[0])-1):
                schum = 0
                for k in range(len(self.data[0]-1)):
                    schum = self.data[j][k]*m[k][i]
                line.append(schum)
            lines.append(line)
        return lines

    def compare(self, m):
        for j in range(len(self.data)):
            for i in range(len(self.data)[j]):
                while self.data[j][i] == m[j][i]:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
```

Comment: Can you provide your code and where you are stuck?

Comment: Looks like a good start, so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing, but it looks like several of your methods should either be returning a new matrix instead of a list, or perhaps modifying the matrix in `self.data` in-place.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to create this yourself? If not, there is already an excellent implementation of this in [numpy](https://numpy.org/)

Comment: sorry, don't get the comment above... I guess it's you matrix class definition, update you question instead; comment field is generally a bad place to place code in